# Typing in Haskell: Passing a number that looks fractional, but will always be an Integer (type aliasing)

Tags: c, haskell, typing

I'm currently learning Haskell using the [Gentle Introduction to Haskell website](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/), and I took a break halfway into section 4 to test my knowledge. I'm trying to implement a "greatest prime in a composite number" function that I used when I was working in C, but I'm having trouble with Haskell's typing system. I'm trying to pass a number that looks like it's a fractional Int, but because I've used modulus to check if it's divisible, I know will evaluate to an Int. Here's the context:

The C: I've super-commented it in case it's unclear, but the code should be fairly straightforward.

```
int highest(long currDom, long lastLargest, long currMax)
/* This is a recursive function that starts at the lowest prime number, 2,
 * and divides into currMax. If a division operation is even - modulus returns 0 -
 * then the prime number in the division is saved as "lastLargest," and the
 * function calls itself again, with MAX now passed as MAX/lastLargest. Otherwise,
 * the function is called with currMax remaining the same value, and the
 * current denominator to try (currDom) incremented by one.
 */
{
    if (currDom > currMax)   //end result - when the current value of MAX is less
        return lastLargest;  //than the value of the denominator we're trying, we're done
    else
    {
        if (currMax % currDom == 0)      //if modulus succeeds, try again with Max/currDom
            return highest(currDom, currDom, currMax/currDom);  //denominator is kept the same incase
        else                                                    //it goes into MAX multiple times -e.g. 2 into 8 
            return highest(currDom+1, lastLargest, currMax);    //else, try the next denominator.
    }

}
```

If you were looking for the highest in 10, for example, you would call this by saying "highest(10, 2, 1)" - you're looking for the highest prime in 10, starting at 2, and the current highest prime in the number is 1. It would return when it tried the number 5 as a divisor for the second time, and saw that curDom is now 1.

The problem is that when I try this in Haskell, on the fourth line in my code, I run into an issue with passing the number divided by a prime that goes into it - it appears to be a fractional Int, but because I've already checked with modulus, I know it's going to resolve to a regular Int. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
greatestPrime                                                   :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
greatestPrime num curPrime greatest | (curPrime > num)          = greatest
greatestPrime num curPrime greatest | (mod num curPrime) > 0    = greatestPrime num (curPrime+1) greatest 
greatestPrime num curPrime greatest | (mod num curPrime) == 0   = greatestPrime (num/curPrime) curPrime greatest
```

If you were trying to get the highest prime in 10, for example, you would call this with "greatestPrime 10 2 1", so that you would start searching at 2, and your current greatest prime number would be 1.

I would appreciate any help with this - either by helping with type aliasing, general code implementation, or even syntax/ code blocking. I'm new to haskell, so there may be a way of writing this that makes more sense; however, I'm not looking for full algorithm rewrites like a sieve. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh, that "gentle" introduction to Haskell that you're reading isn't really that gentle—and it's pretty dated by this point.  The two best resources to learn Haskell these days are [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [*Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/).  I'd read them in that order, too—*Learn You a Haskell* is more theoretical but also gentler, while *Real World Haskell* is more practical and a bit harder (IMO).

Comment: @sacundim - Thanks, "Learn You a Haskell" is certainly a bit gentler. I have to say, I do like "Gentle Introduction"'s pacing, though - it makes me pause and try to comprehend things a lot, which makes things sink in more - not to mention I was able to download it and read it while on a flight, which is a bonus. I'm reading "Learn You" now, though I'll probably go back to "Gentle" at some point.

Comment: The thing with the "Gentle Introduction" is that it starts out simple, then at one point there is a huge jump in complexity.  As I recall it, this point is when it starts talking about IO and monads...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `/` operator has type `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, which means that it only works on `Fractional` types like `Float`, `Double` and `Rational`, and not integers.

Use [`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3adiv) for integer division.

```
> 10 `div` 2
5
> 7 `div` 2
3
```

There's also [`quot`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aquot), which rounds towards zero instead of negative infinity:

```
> (-7) `div` 2
-4
> (-7) `quot` 2
-3
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. As an aside, what are the backticks for?

Comment: @MarshallConover: They turn functions into operators, so ```7 `div` 2``` is the same as `div 7 2`. Likewise, you can use parentheses to turn an operator into a function, so `2 + 3` is the same as `(+) 2 3`.

Comment: Note that `quot` is a bit faster than `div` because it's the operator implemented directly on the cpu, `div` has to process the results because it handles negative results differently. (similarly `rem` is faster than `mod` ) The difference is notable when you use one of those operator in a big loop.